# How to make a BinaryField editable in django?

Tags: python, django, forms, model

Here is my code:

```
#models.py
class Upload(models.Model):
    #image = models.FileField()    #working code
    image = models.BinaryField()   #not working

#forms.py
class UploadModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields = ('image')
        labels = { 'image': "Upload Image" }
        widgets = {
            'image' : forms.FileInput(attrs={'multiple': True})
        }
```

When I run that, it throws the following error:

> 'image' cannot be specified for Upload model form as it is a non-editable field

But when I change the `BinaryField` to `FileField`, it is working fine. The problem is, in my database, `FileField` has a DataType `char` which is not what I want. I want the DataType to be `blob`.

**Edit:**
I forgot to say that I have tried:

> `image = models.BinaryField(editable = True)`

and it is not working.

Comment: It says here [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield) that "It is not possible to include a `BinaryField` in a `ModelForm`." Did you try a `forms.Form` in place of `ModelForm`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and it is working fine but I really want to use `ModelForm`. Can I make a custom `ModelForm`?...

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that this has been changed in [Django 2.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield)

> Django 2.1:
>
> Older versions don’t allow setting editable to True.

Answer (score 0):

This link would likely help you out. You could still set the type of the field to one of the available options:

http://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/resizable_text_binary_fields.html

Hope that helps!